# Como adicionar uma mascara de email inputmask em um campo input dentro de um tabela?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Como adicionar uma mascara de e-mail [inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) em um campo `input` dentro de uma tabela `html` criado dinamicamente?
Exemplo:

```
<tr role="row" data-row-index="0">
    <td class="text-center">
        <input id="chkSelecionado" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td class="form-group">@Html.TextBox("Contatos[0].Nome", "", new { @class = "form-control required" })</td>
    <td class="form-group">@Html.TextBox("Contatos[0].Telefone", "", new { @class = "form-control required telefone" })</td>
    <td class="form-group">@Html.TextBox("Contatos[0].Celular1", "", new { @class = "form-control celular" })</td>
    <td class="form-group">@Html.TextBox("Contatos[0].Email", "", new { @class = "form-control required" })</td>
</tr>

$(document).ready(function(){( )};
```

Comment: Você poderia dar uma classe para esse input de e-mail e chamar um .mask na classe após a criação dinâmica da tabela.

Comment: Faz exatamente a mesma coisa que iria fazer fora da tabela, igual o amigo disse, só coloca um classname pra identificar.

Comment: Ok!, fiz assim: <td class="form-group">@Html.TextBox("Contatos[0].Email", "", new { @class = "form-control required **email**" })</td>, onde criei um  `$(".email").inputmask({... `, funcionou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vi que resolveu, mas vou dar um resposta pra caso precise setar mais de uma máscara, sem ter que chamar o método de novo:

Exemplo HTML:

```
<input type='text' class='mask' data-mask='cpf' name='cpf'>
<input type='text' class='mask' data-mask='telefone' name='telefone'>
<input type='text' class='mask' data-mask='email' name='email'>
```

Disparando no foco a função que acrescenta a máscara:

```
$(document).on('focusin','.mask',function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var mask = $this.data('mask');
    makeMask(mask, $this);
});
```

Função que seta a máscara:

```
var makeMask = function (mask, $this) {
    if (mask === 'cpf') {
        $this.inputmask("999.999.999-99");
    }
    if (mask === 'telefone') {
        $this.inputmask({"mask": "+55 (99) [9] 9999-9999"});
    }
    if (mask === 'mail') {
        $this.inputmask("email");
    }
}
```

Vantagens disso:

Sempre que precisar de uma máscara em qualquer lugar, basta acrescentar o classname 'mask', e um data-attr (data-mask) com alguma mascara que você tenha definido em sua função.